# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.../node_modules/node-sass/vendor'

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I am having an issue running my node application on a different computer than the one I usually use. After a lot of troubleshooting:

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.../node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
```

A posting that I was reading suggested that I run `sudo npm install -g node-sass`, which gives me the following error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '...nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build'
```

I then tried to run `sudo npm rebuild node-sass` but I'm getting the same error message:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '.../node_modules/node-sass/build'
```

I then ran `sudo npm install -g node-sass --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` but it also didn't work:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.../node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't node-sass working? Why isn't sudo working properly?

Answer (score 42):

Windows. Try below

```
node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: The 1st command `node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js` by itself solved the problem for me, I didn't need the rebuild

Comment: YES!!!  Give this man a beer! This will also work in Mac too for ionic. Thanks.

Comment: whether from VS-x or a Command window, have Administrator perms before doing this.

Comment: First command solved (Linux too), missing binary (install.js launched download -> Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v5.0.0/linux-x64-83_binding.node
). Don't know why module was installed without init that part.

Comment: It may be that node-sass is not installed at all, as it was in my case, just do npm i node-sass

Answer (score 1):

1. Most probably it's not `node-sass` issue. This sometimes happens when you use different OS to install node-sass. As it uses some native components, the npm install must only be done one OS. Do not copy node_modules from some other place. Do a fresh install.
2. Have you tried deleting the node_modules directory and running `npm install` again?
3. Are you working on Windows machione where the npm install was done using a Ubuntu shell (inside windows) and now you are trying to install again from the windows command line? If so, dont. Use only one shell.
4. Finally if none of these help, then its possible a user permission issue. Check if you can get super user access `sudo su -` and then try doing a fresh npm install.

Comment: Mine was a permissions issue, solved by opening a command window as Admin

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not has the rights to write in the folder you are trying. You are using 3 `...` so it goes to the folder `/Users` on the second one you have `...nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules`

Comment: Those are just placeholders...it's not actually [...]. How can I gain the permission?

Comment: I was able to run it using `sudo npm install -g node-sass --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root` but it hasn't solved the problem. I think the problem lies in the node-sass/vendor which doesn't seem to be found.

Comment: Yeah! using sudo is the main option, you can also use su, and change to root user.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a missing node-sass dependency or broken node-sass package issue.

You can resolve this by the following steps:

- Install `node-sass` globally, if it is not installed in your system.

  ```
  npm install -g node-sass
  ```
- Open command prompt/terminal on the project root directory and execute the following commands.

  ```
  nodejs node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
  npm rebuild node-sass
  ```